# I am trying to run this code but i am getting this error : RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (16x196608 and 65536x16384)

Tags: pytorch, autoencoder

```
class DenoiseAutoencoder(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(DenoiseAutoencoder, self).__init__()
    # encoder
    self.enc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=256 * 256, out_features=16384)
    self.enc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=16384, out_features=4096)
    self.enc3 = nn.Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024)
    self.enc4 = nn.Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=256)
    self.enc5 = nn.Linear(in_features=256, out_features=128)
    self.enc6 = nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=64)
    self.enc7 = nn.Linear(in_features=64, out_features=32)
    self.enc8 = nn.Linear(in_features=32, out_features=16)
    # decoder 
    self.dec1 = nn.Linear(in_features=16, out_features=32)
    self.dec2 = nn.Linear(in_features=32, out_features=64)
    self.dec3 = nn.Linear(in_features=64, out_features=128)
    self.dec4 = nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=256)
    self.dec5 = nn.Linear(in_features=256, out_features=1024)
    self.dec6 = nn.Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096)
    self.dec7 = nn.Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=16384)
    self.dec8 = nn.Linear(in_features=16834, out_features=256 * 256)
def forward(self, x):
     
    x = F.relu(self.enc1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.enc2(x))
    x = F.relu(self.enc3(x))
    x = F.relu(self.enc4(x))
    x = F.relu(self.enc5(x))
    x = F.relu(self.enc6(x))
    x = F.relu(self.enc7(x))
    x = F.relu(self.enc8(x))

    x = F.relu(self.dec1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.dec2(x))
    x = F.relu(self.dec3(x))
    x = F.relu(self.dec4(x))
    x = F.relu(self.dec5(x))
    x = F.relu(self.dec6(x))
    x = F.relu(self.dec7(x))
    x = F.relu(self.dec8(x))
    return x
   net = DenoiseAutoencoder()
   print(net)
```

I tried implementing all the solution in stack over flow for this error but none of it worked.

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (16x196608 and 65536x16384)

i don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

In your code output features(16384) in self.dec7 is not same as input features(16834) in self.dec8.
I guess this should work.